# Inline image not showing

Tags: org-babel, inline-image

I am trying to display images inline in emacs, but for however reason the behaviour is not stable within the same document. Here is the problem:

The below chunk works as expected:

[image]

However, in the same document, the following chunk does not:

[image]

This small box gets printed, but no figure.

- How do I debug this?

Comment: Please don't use images to present code: Org mode's motto is "your life in plain text" and plain text is infinitely preferable: you can paste the text of your code and put it in between triple backquotes (see the Help on how to use Markdown in Emacs SE). That way, people can cut and paste the code into their own Emacs session to try things out. Also, make your code examples self-sufficient: you are using a variable `carbs` in your first code block but you don't provide it, which means that if I decide to answer the question, I have to figure out what that variable should look like and ...

Comment: ... then construct my own example. If you provide that definition, you make it that much easier for people to try out your code and possibly come up with an answer. Otherwise, they may well decide that it's going to take them too long and that their time is spent better elsewhere.